# @pact and @pactVerfication have to be in same class

Tags: testing, microservices, pact

I am looking to invoke the @pactverification test from consumer code instead of creating a dummy HttpClient and verifying the same. Does the @pact and @pactVerfication have to be in same class? Can we seperate the contracts with actual tests? If yes, how does the @pactverification test know which contract to look for ?Please let me know if I am missing anything

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to choose the right tool for the right job, and Pact may not be the best tool for what you're trying to do if you're trying to use it in a way for which it was not designed.

Please come and have a talk to us on https://slack.pact.io about what you're trying to achieve, as your use case does not make sense to me, and I can't give you a general answer that I would be happy to leave as a guide for anyone else with a similar question (which is what stackoverflow is good for).